# Почему многие говорят "Третий рейх" вместо правильного "Третий райх"?

Tags: другое

Не понимаю, почему люди говорят неправильно. Кто-нибудь может объяснить? Ввиду неграмотности?

Согласно правилам произношения в немецком языке, дифтонг ei (Reich) произносится как 'ай'. Вот и возникает вопрос, почему люди не знают этого.

Comment: Да все люди знают. Но не обязаны следовать.

Comment: Давайте писать безграмотно, зная правила русского языка!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Существует два термина: рейх и Третий рейх, с их значением можно ознакомиться по словарю:

Рейх (нем. Reich (инф.) [ˈʁaɪç]) — немецкое слово для обозначения ряда земель, подчиненных одной власти. В современном русском языке термин рейх употребляется почти исключительно по отношению к гитлеровской Германии.

Третий рейх (нем. Drittes Reich — «Третья империя», «Третья держава») — неофициальное название Германского государства с 24 марта 1933 года по 23 мая 1945 года.

Эти термины входят в ЛЕКСИКУ РУССКОГО ЯЗЫКА с такой записью и с таким произношением, и именно в таком виде их должны  употреблять грамотные люди.

Вопрос о том, почему не сохранилось произношение первоисточника, относится к этимологии. Заимствованное слово может соответствовать как звуковой, так и буквенной форме исходного варианта, также на него  могут влиять уже существующие традиции для  записи подобных слов.

Answer (score 3):

До самого недавнего времени сочетания "ei" было принято передавать через "ей". Сравните: *лейб- (leib), Гейне (Heine), шлейф (Schleife) и др.* Изменять уже вошедшее в употребление слово не имеет никакого смысла.

Скорей всего запись через "е" связана во-первых с влиянием французского языка, где это слово читается как "р**[ɛ]**йх, а во-вторых с диалектами самого немецкого, в некоторых из которых произношение через "э" почти наверняка возможно.

Answer (score 3):

Вопрос, собственно в том, что важнее: транскрипция или транслитерация.
Попросту говоря, в первом случае слово (обычно - имя собственное или приближающееся к нему по функции) передается средствами другого алфавита максимально близко к произношению, во втором - к написанию. Вопрос решался по-разному в разное время и в зависимости от конкретного имени и языка-источника, но все-таки второй подход, транслитерация, обычно побеждал, так как зрительный образ слова воспринимался более существенным (для поиска по литературе, например). В русском слово написанное "рейх" прочесть "райх" просто невозможно.
Так и закрепилось. 
Стоит ли сейчас что-то менять? Вряд ли, никаких существенных благ от того не возникнет, а "накладные расходы", могут оказаться существенными. Хотя по современным представлением во всех источниках, даже неспециализированных, принято давать все возможные варианты написания и произношения на всех имеющих отношение языках, так что вопрос с поиском обычно никаких сложностей не несет.

С другой стороны, Рейх, даже третий - это ж не только условное имя собственное. Это еще и **перевод** слова на русский. И совершенно не обязательно, чтобы заимствованное, **переведенное** слово следовало бы фонетике языка-источника. Так что и тут не вижу никаких причин для недоумения.

Answer (score 2):

Встречный вопрос: **фонетическим нормам какого языка должны подчиняться заимствованные слова?**

Для меня оба этих вопроса звучат несколько риторически. :)

Во-первых, есть общая закономерность: кроме группы "исключений", *заимствованные слова, входя в состав другого языка, подчиняются его традициям и нормам*.

Во-вторых, при вхождении заимствований в речь происходит **фонетическое освоение** – то есть изменение звукового облика слова соответственно законам принимающего языка.
Судите сами: как сделать иностранные слова – часто труднопроизносимые, чужеродные для слуха и артикуляции русского человека – частью живой речи, не придав им некоего "благозвучия" с точки зрения традиционной русской фонетики?

Не стоит забывать, что 2,5‒3 века назад (когда активизировалось заимствование немецких слов), распространение иностранных языков происходило гораздо чаще посредством книг, нежели через общение с прямыми носителями чужой речи. 
То есть совсем не так, как это обстоит сейчас – благодаря активному международному обмену, трудовой миграции, телефонии, Интернету (и другим техническим достижениям).

Помимо немецкого, в классическое обучение 18-19 вв. были введены латынь, греческий (позднее и французский) языки – и преподавали их отнюдь не "природные носители"...
Поэтому многие слова и термины **озвучивались согласно написанию**, входя в русскую речь именно в такой транскрипции.

*( Подробнее о традициях русского произношения **«eu» и «ei»** Вы можете прочитать [здесь](http://lingvoforum.net/index.php?topic=6036.0), **об адаптации немецких заимствований** в русском литературном языке – [здесь](http://www.dissercat.com/content/adaptatsiya-nemetskikh-leksicheskikh-zaimstvovanii-v-russkom-literaturnom-yazyke-na-material) ).*

Answer (score 0):

Я не знаток немецкого языка, но предполагаю, что просто в свое время кто-то прочел его по принципу "как пишется, так и слышится", и оно вошло в язык. Вроде того, как некоторые говорят "Сандра Буллок" вместо "Баллок" или "мадэ ин Чина"))))

Comment: Вследствие безграмотности, наверное ;)

Comment: Но сейчас же можно приучить людей говорить правильно, не так ли?

Comment: >Вроде того, как некоторые говорят "Сандра Буллок" вместо "Баллок"

Сандра как раз Буллок. Фамилия немецкого происхождения и читается через "у".

Comment: Tagirix, это правильно с точки зрения немецкого языка, а наш ресурс посвящён русскому, который не обязан следовать правилам немецких правописания и произношения.